# Java convert array to IntBuffer

Tags: java

There was no answer for this at google, so I'm asking

```
static float vertices_textures[] = {
        //vertices            //positions
        -1.0f, -1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f,
        1.0f, -1.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f,
        -1.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f,
        1.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f
    };

Buffer vertices_textures_buffer = IntBuffer.allocate(vertices_textures.length);
```

Do I have to iterate over the `vertices_textures` array and set each element of `vertices_textures_buffer`?

Comment: Do you need an `IntBuffer`? Could you use a `FloatBuffer`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Do I have to iterate over the vertices_textures array and set each
>   element of vertices_textures_buffer?

Yes, because you're putting `floats` into an `IntBuffer`.

If you had an `int[]`, you could use `IntBuffer.wrap(int[]);`.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a way to populate the Buffer using streams.

```java
      Buffer vertices_textures_buffer = IntBuffer.wrap(
            IntStream.range(0, vertices_textures.length)
            .map(n -> (int) vertices_textures[n]).toArray());
```

And verify

```java
      for (int i : (int[]) vertices_textures_buffer.array()) {
         System.out.print(i + " ");
      }
```